# Not sure how to flush buffer string x86

Tags: linux, x86, buffer, overflow, flush

The goal of my code below to mimmic the cat program.  It takes an input, and then spits it back out.
Such as:

```
$ Hi how are you
$ Hi how are you
$ good
$ good
```

What is happening though is:

```
$ Hi how are you
$ Hi how are you
$ good
$ good
$ow are you
```

My string is not being removed from my buffer and so if the input is shorter the second time, it will spit out the extra characters that have not been written over.  I was wondering if anyone knew how to clear the buffer so this would not occur.  Thanks

```
    .file    "rand.c"

    .section    .data
.buffer: 
    .space        10
.len:
    .space      1

    .globl    _start
_start:
pushl    %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
andl    $-16, %esp
subl    $16, %esp

loop:    
movl    $3, %eax
movl    $1, %ebx
movl    $.buffer, %ecx
movl    $100, %edx
int    $0x80

movl    $4, %eax
movl    $1, %ebx
movl    $.buffer, %ecx
movl    $100, %edx
int    $0x80    
jmp    loop

movl    $1, %eax
movl    $0, %ebx
int    $0x80
```

Comment: Try setting `count` (`edx`) to the length of the string when printing it, rather than having the hardcoded value 100.

Comment: @Michael, do you know how to set it equal to the length of the string?